# Why values larger than 17 in the following string are matching?

Tags: javascript, regex

Why values larger than 17 are matching in the following string?

```
    "1,2,17,18,19,181111".match(/^\b((1[0-7]|[1-9])\,?)+$/g )
```

Comment: Because comma is an optional match

Comment: `inputStr.split( "," ).filter( s => +s <= 17 )`;

Comment: How does this relate to Perl or PCRE?

Comment: @Xufox When I was typing the question, SO itself suggested to add these tags, otherwise I wouldn't.

Comment: You may use this regex: [`^(?:1[0-7]|[1-9])(?:,(?:1[0-7]|[1-9]))*$`](https://regex101.com/r/ldikUR/1)

Comment: because 1-9 matches.....

Comment: @anubhava Thanks. It worked. Maybe if you would like to, you could write an elaborate answer explaining why mine didn't work and how yours (looks really complicated!) worked. An answer would be futuristic.

Comment: @edam “Suggested” doesn’t mean _necessitated_…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex is pretty close but problem is comma is an optional match and that lets regex match across the previous matched number. Word boundary or `\b` should be part of the group to make sure you only match complete number:

```
^(?:\b(?:1[0-7]|[1-9])\,?)+$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ldikUR/2)

Note that old faishoned unrolled regex as this one will still perform better:

```
^(?:1[0-7]|[1-9])(?:,(?:1[0-7]|[1-9]))*$
```

Comment: Very nice answer :)

Answer (score 2):

A non-regex solution could be

```
var inputStr = "1,2,17,18,19,181111";

var output = inputStr.split( "," ).filter( s => +s <= 17 );
```

**Demo**

```js
var inputStr = "1,2,17,18,19,181111";

var output = inputStr.split( "," ).filter( s => +s <= 17 );

console.log( output );
```

Comment: Nice, thanks :)
But I would like to have a regex solution :)

Comment: @edam sure, try out anubhava's solution.

Comment: regex is the wrong tool for the job when you're matching on numeric values.

Comment: @Sobrique Actually it's a comma separated number list in which no number can go above 17. So it's a string in essence.

Comment: But regex doesn't "do" numeric values. It does text patterns.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var inputStr = "1,2,17,18,19,181111";

const output = inputStr.split(',').filter(number => parseInt(number) < 17).join(',');

console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

A moment ago, Perl tag was still there...

```
$ perl -wE '$s = "1,2,17,18,19,181111";
            say $1 while $s =~ /\G(1[0-7]|[1-9])(?:,|$)/g'
1
2
17
```

\G matches where the last match stopped, so you can't e.g. skip 1811 and match the final 11.

Answer (score 0):

The regex you are looking for is the following:

```
(?<=^|,)(1[0-7]|\d)(?=,|$)
```

In this live example on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/tBjqgJ/1) you can see how it works. You are looking for either 1 followed by 1-7 or any single digit enclosed by either the beginning of the string (`^`) or a comma on the left and the end of the string (`$`) or a comma on the right side.

Your regex does not what you want because when saying `((1[0-7]|[0-9])\,?)+` you match one or more single digits that **may** be followed by a comma.

Comment: Your live example matches everything in the string! But I expected no number larger than 17 would match!

Comment: It does. When your example is a multiline string you just have to add the /m flag at the end of the regex so ^ and $ matches the beginning/end of each line: /(?<=^|,)(1[0-7]|\d)(?=,|$)/mg. See here: [Example](https://regex101.com/r/tBjqgJ/2)

Answer (score 0):

Here are two options, one using array filter and another one using regex.

With regex, you need to use word boundaries (`\b`) and set a value 0-9 (first option) or [0-1][0-7] (you don't want 20,21..).

I'm not sure what's your idea, but i highly recommend array 'filter' instead of regex for this case.

```js
//    "1,2,17,18,19,181111".match(/^\b((1[0-7]|[1-9])\,?)+$/g )


// Without regex
const result = "1,2,17,18,19,181111"
                .split(',')
                .filter(i => parseInt(i) <= 17);

// With regex
const regexResult = "1,2,17,18,19,181111"
                      .match(/\b([0-9]|([0-1][0-7]))\b/g);

console.log(result);
console.log(regexResult)
```